# What does 'add dynamic method' do in Groovy/IntelliJ?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

When I use an undefined method in Groovy/IntelliJ, and I press alt-Enter, I get the following option: "Add dynamic method". When I do it, I get a "dynamic properties" windows with a new dynamic property.

I don't understand how to use this dynamic property/method. Where do I define it? What does it mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This page in the documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/GRVY/Dynamic+Methods+and+Properties) explains it.

Basically, you can use this method to tell the IDE about dynamic properties or methods you have set up, and then the Syntax Highlighter and Code Completion can handle it.

Without this, I believe you would end up with valid code marked as erroneous, and things missing from the code completion window.