# Groovy and dynamic methods: need groovy veteran enlightment

Tags: groovy, dynamic

First, I have to say that I really like Groovy and all the good stuff it is bringing to the Java dev world. But since I'm using it for more than little scripts, I have some concerns.

In this [Groovy help page about dynamic vs static typing](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Runtime+vs+Compile+time,+Static+vs+Dynamic), there is this statement about the absence of compilation error/warning when you have typo in your code because it could be a call to a method added later at runtime:

> It might be scary to do away with all of your static typing and
>   compile time checking at first. But many Groovy veterans will attest
>   that it makes the code cleaner, easier to refactor, and, well, more
>   dynamic.

I'm pretty agree with the 'more dynamic' part, but not with cleaner and easier to refactor:
For the other two statements I'm not sure: from my Groovy beginner perspective, this is resulting in less code, but in more difficult to read later and in more trouble to maintain (can not rely on the IDE anymore to find who is declaring a dynamic method and who is using one).

To clarify, I find that reading groovy code is very pleasant, I love the collection and closure (concise and expressive way of tackle complicated problem). 
But I have a lot of trouble in these situations:

- no more auto-completion inside 'builder' using Map (Of Map (of Map))
  everywhere
- confusing dynamic methods call (you don't know if it is a typo or a
  dynamic name)
- method extraction is more complicated inside closure (often resulting in code duplicate: 'it is only a small closure after all')
- hard to guess closure parameters when you have to write one for a method of a subsystem

no more learning by browsing the code: you have to use text search instead

I can only saw some benefits with GORM, but in this case the dynamic method are wellknown and my IDE is aware of them (so it is more looking like a systematic code generation than dynamic method for me)

I would be very glad to learn from groovy veteran how they can attest of these benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *does* lead to different classes of bugs and processes. It also makes writing tests faster and more natural, helping to alleviate the bug issues.

Discovering where behavior is defined, and used, can be problematic. There isn't a great way around it, although IDEs are getting better at it over time.

Your code shouldn't be more difficult to *read*--mainline code should be *easier* to read. The dynamic behavior should disappear into the application, and be documented appropriately for developers that need to understand functionality at those levels.

Magic does make discovery more difficult. This implies that other means of documentation, particularly human-readable tests (think easyb, spock, etc.) and prose, become that much more important.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat old, but i'd like to share my experience if someone comes looking for some thoughts on the topic:

Right now we are using eclipse 3.7 and groovy-eclipse 2.7 on a small team (3 developers) and since we don't have tests scripts, mostly of our groovy development we do by explicitly using types.

For example, when using service classes methods:

```
void validate(Product product) {
  // groovy stuff
}

Box pack(List<Product> products) {
  def box = new Box()
  box.value = products.inject(0) { total, item ->
    // some BigDecimal calculations =)
  }
  box
}
```

We usually fill out the type, which enable eclipse to autocomplete and, most important, allows us to refactor code, find usages, etc..

This blocks us from using metaprogramming, except for Categories which i found that are supported and is detected by groovy-eclipse.

Still, Groovy is pretty good and a LOT of our business logic is in groovy code.

We had two issues in production code when using groovy, and both cases were due bad manual testing.

We also have a lot of XML building and parsing, and we validate it before sending it to webservices and the likes.

There's a small script we use to connect to an internal system whose usage is very restricted (and not needed in other parts of the system). This code i developed using entirely dynamic typing, overriding methods using metaclass and all that stuff, but this is an exception.

I think groovy 2.0 (with groovy-eclipse coming along, of course) and it's @TypeChecked will be great for those of us that uses groovy as a "java++".

Answer (score 0):

To me there are 2 types of refactoring:

1. IDE based refactoring (extract to method, rename method, introduce variable, etc.).
2. Manual refactoring. (moving a method to a different class, changing the return value of a method)

For IDE based refactoring I haven't found an IDE that does as good of a job with Groovy as it does with Java.  For example in eclipse when you extract to method it looks for duplicate instances to refactor to call the method instead of having duplicated code.  For Groovy, that doesn't seem to happen.

Manual refactoring is where I believe that you **could** see refactoring made easier.  Without tests though I would agree that it is probably harder.

The statement at cleaner code is **100% accurate.**  I would venture a guess that good Java to good Groovy code is at least a 3:1 reduction in lines of code.  Being a newbie at Groovy though I would strive to learn at least 1 new way to do something everyday.  Something that greatly helped me improve my Groovy was to simply read the APIs.  I feel that Collection, String, and List are probably the ones that have the most functionality and I used the most to help make my Groovy code actually Groovy.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html

http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html

http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html

Since you edited the question I'll edit my answer :)

One thing you can do is tell intellij about the dynamic methods on your objects: [What does 'add dynamic method' do in Groovy/IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757379/what-does-add-dynamic-method-do-in-groovy-intellij).  That might help a little bit.

Another trick that I use is to type my objects when doing the initial coding and remove the typing when I'm done.  For example I can never seem to remember if it's .substring(..) or .subString(..) on a String.  So if you type your object you get a little better code completion.

As for your other bullet points, I'd really need to look at some code to be able to give a better answer.

Comment: Moving method and changing signature are well done by IDE. Other kind of refactoring I miss is extracting a superclass/interface from current class. By clean, you mean more expressive or with less mess ? Because with all the magic, I find the code less massive but harder to read, with lots of warning in my IDE. Sure List and String are really groovy, but with some good libraries (Guava for instance), it is possible to have good looking Java too :)

Comment: By clean I mean more expressive and less mess :)  Can you share a GIST of something that you find hard to read?  Also what IDE do you use?

Comment: Please see the bullet list in my edited post. I'm using IDEA, and it is known as having a good support for groovy.